# Embedding an SVG into React with react-svg

Tags: javascript, reactjs, svg, npm

I have a simple `react` component, and I wish to embed the `svg` specified in the path below:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactSVG from 'react-svg';


const FrontPage = () => (

  <div>

    <p>there is some writing between these tags</p>

    <ReactSVG path="anImage.svg" />

  </div>

);


export default FrontPage;
```

Although `webpack` compiles successfully (the app loads), the browser returns a 404 error (not found) on the `svg` file. I have installed the `npm` `react-svg` package, but it appears that I am using it incorrectly. There is a GitHub link to an example of it being employed 
[here](https://github.com/tanem/react-svg/blob/master/examples/issue-49/fill/index.js), so I don't think it is a path issue - the `svg` is currently in the same folder (called components) as the component itself.

**How can I get the `svg` to successfully render?**

---

To install the [package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-svg), I ran: `npm install react-svg --save`.

Comment: check in the console, the path to the svg

Comment: Hi Gautam Naik, I checked the path, I think it is correct. I am using the relative path, not the absolute path.